# angular 1.5 component template webpack require() causes error

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, pug, webpack

I'm using angular 1.5.3 with es6, webpack and jade templates.

Everything works as expected except for the component's templates.

**This works**

```
var cmpnt = {
    template: '<div>test</div>'
}
```

**This also works** (when I manually create the html file)

```
var cmpnt = {
    template: require('./component.html')
}
```

**This does NOT work**

```
var cmpnt = {
    template: require('./component.jade')
}
```

In the browser console, I get

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localsProvider <- locals`

The `.jade` file exists, and I'm using `require('./template.jade')` in many other places of the app without problems.

Any ideas? Any more info I can provide?

Comment: What does component.jade look like? When you get an error like that one you've had. It means you're trying to inject something (likely a service) called locals into one of your controllers/services/configs/etc...

Comment: At the moment it is just `h1 test`. I'm not injecting anything anywhere in that component. It's just a stub.

Comment: What about over the rest of your application?

Comment: @MathewBerg what do you mean? The rest is not just a stub and it works great. Only the component is problematic.

Comment: Is there any place in your entire application where you inject locals.

Comment: No. Nowhere in the entire app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jade-loader` returns a function. You cannot to pass that function to template, you must to invoke the function before pass it

```
var cmpnt = {
    template: require('./component.jade')();
}
```

note the call of function after `require`

Comment: great solution to my problem, but I am a bit amazed that this is required in a component but not for example in a template attribute of a UI-Route. It's error puzzled me for at least an hour

Comment: for component, the call of function is required, but for directive, isn't.